# Instagram Graph API, "media" endpoint and error: "An unknown error has occurred"

Tags: instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I'm using the Instagram Graph API and the "media" endpoint, to create a container to upload one [image from this public URL](https://www.sample-videos.com/img/Sample-jpg-image-100kb.jpg).

[Following the reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-user/media?locale=en_US#request-syntax) I did a call to the media endpoint:

```
POST https://graph.facebook.com/v15.0/{your-instagram-business-id}/media
?image_url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.sample-videos.com%2Fimg%2FSample-jpg-image-100kb.jpg
&is_carousel_item=False
&caption=this%2Bis%2Ba%2Btest
&access_token={your-token}
```

**but I always get the response:**

```
{
   "error":{
      "message":"An unknown error has occurred.",
      "type":"OAuthException",
      "code":1,
      "fbtrace_id":"{unique code}"
   }
}
```

My token is valid, and it is a long lived token. I also followed all the [image specifications](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-user/media?locale=en_US#image-specifications). I also tried to use the "API Graph exploration tool", but I always get the same error.

Someone had the same problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, after struggling one day because of the generic error.

It seems that the [website where I got the image](https://www.sample-videos.com/img/Sample-jpg-image-100kb.jpg), had a bad https certificate (see the attached image). Changing the url, using another site, I solved the problem.

I also opened a bug in the Meta for Developers platform to ask a detailed error for this case, instead of a generic error.

[image]